# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.id')

Tags: react-native

i have created two component  in the first component I have an object and I want to display on the the other screen component I passed it as parameter but when I liked it through error here is my code

```
const Tweets = ({ navigation }) => (
  <ExpoScreen>
    <Text>Tweets</Text>
    <Button
      title="View Tweet"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TweetDetails", { id: 1 })}
    />
  </ExpoScreen>
);

const TweetDetails = ({ route }) => (
  <ExpoScreen>
    <Text>Tweets details {route.Params.id}</Text>
  </ExpoScreen>
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Tweets">
    <Stack.Screen name="Tweets" component={Tweets} />
    <Stack.Screen name="TweetDetails" component={TweetDetails} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: why is your params capital? like P in their capital

Comment: params not Params. It is not capital, Also you need control it too:
```<Text>Tweets details {route?.params?.id}</Text>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is like P is  capital in your params.

Hopeit helps. feel free for doubts